# Need SQL trigger to split string based on dash delimeter

Tags: sql-server-2005, delimiter, insert-update

I am looking for the right syntax for a MSSQL 2005 trigger that will split the value of one column and update 4 other columns.

- Database: `TestDB`
- Table: `UploadAppTable`

Before

```
|OriginalFile                 | EmployeeID | EmployeeTitle | Location | ApplicationID 
|0146291-ITDCCT-02-1367413404 |            |               |          |
```

What I need if the following. I need the SQL trigger to update the table when the new record gets inserted.

Output

```
|OriginalFile                 | EmployeeID | EmployeeTitle | Location | ApplicationID
|0146291-ITDCCT-02-1367413404 | 0146291    | ITDCCT        | 02       | 1367413404
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To tell you the truth I have never written an update statement that will update multiple columns. so I need suggestions so I can try something. I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Looks like "CHARINDEX" is the way to go to split the string using a delimeter. I just don't know the right syntax. I also need to add this to a SQL trigger.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate the values you can use dbo.SplitStrings_CTE function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@List nvarchar(max), @Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @returns TABLE(val nvarchar(max), [level] int, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([level]))
AS
BEGIN
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List)) AS val,
         CAST(STUFF (@List + @Delimiter, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List), '') AS nvarchar(max)) AS stval,
         1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval)),
         CAST(STUFF (stval, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval), '') AS nvarchar(max)),
         [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  INSERT @returns
  SELECT REPLACE(val, ' ', '') AS val, [level]
  FROM cte
  RETURN
END
```

After creating a function, use this UPDATE statement

```
;WITH cte AS
 (    
  SELECT t.OriginalFile, t.EmployeeID, t.EmployeeTitle, t.Location, t.ApplicationID, 
         NewEmployeeID = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 1 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewEmployeeTitle = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 2 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewLocation = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(),
         NewApplicationID = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 4 THEN o.val END) OVER()
  FROM dbo.UploadAppTable t CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(t.OriginalFile, '-') o  
  )
  UPDATE cte
  SET EmployeeID = NewEmployeeID,
      EmployeeTitle = NewEmployeeTitle,
      Location = NewLocation,
      ApplicationID = NewApplicationID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f87d2/3)

OR UPDATE statement for a multiple update

```
;WITH cte AS
 (    
  SELECT t.OriginalFile, t.EmployeeID, t.EmployeeTitle, t.Location, t.ApplicationID, 
         NewEmployeeID = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 1 THEN o.val END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.OriginalFile),
         NewEmployeeTitle = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 2 THEN o.val END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.OriginalFile),
         NewLocation = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 3 THEN o.val END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.OriginalFile),
         NewApplicationID = MAX(CASE WHEN o.level = 4 THEN o.val END) OVER(PARTITION BY t.OriginalFile)
  FROM dbo.UploadAppTable t CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(t.OriginalFile, '-') o  
  )
  UPDATE cte
  SET EmployeeID = NewEmployeeID,
      EmployeeTitle = NewEmployeeTitle,
      Location = NewLocation,
      ApplicationID = NewApplicationID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3e14/1)

Comment: Hi @Alexander Fedorenko Thank you so much for the help. Function and the update statement work but now I have the issue of whenever adding a new entry. it updates all my previous entries with the latest. Tried it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25a7e/1/2)

Comment: It works, I just needed to add a where statement right after my FROM.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If multiple UPDATE statement is necessary for you, then add PARTITION BY t.OriginalFile expression into OVER() clause. Answer updated;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like`OriginalFile.Split('-')`, right? Sadly there is no intrinsic string splitting available in SQL Server, you will have to roll your own . Handily, Erland Sommarskog has saved everyone the trouble of having to worry about it too much with some excellent articles which you can find [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Comment: Thank you @Steve Pettifer. I will look into that link on your last post.  I wonder how would you approach the opposite of a concatenation. Splitting dash delimited string into rows of data.

Comment: Err...that's exactly what I just posted! Concatenation is easy, but of no concern here. You want to split a string based on a given delimiter. My little chunk of pseudo-code (`OriginalFile.Split('-')`) is actually valid .Net syntax that demonstrates what I believe you want to do. My point is that there is no intrinsic function for this in T-SQL, nor is there an equivalent to arrays. Therefore you must create your own function to split the string and return the values or use things like table-valued parameters.